# How to close Pyqt5 program from QML?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qml, signals-slots, pyqt5

I started a project in Qt Creator initially with a C++ backend, but then switched it to use PyQt5. I have a main.qml, where when I press a button called `Exit`, I call `Qt.quit()`.

However, I get a `General Message` stating: `Signal QQmlEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it.`

My question is, how do I receive this signal and handle it?

Code:

main.py:

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtQml
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject pyqtSignal


class DestinyManager,(QtGui.QGuiApplication):
    """the app self"""
    def __init__(self, argv):
        super(DestinyManager, self).__init__(argv)

    # Define a new signal called 'trigger' that has no arguments.
    trigger = pyqtSignal()

    def connect_and_emit_trigger(self):
        # Connect the trigger signal to a slot.
        self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)
        self.menuItem_Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        # Emit the signal.
        self.trigger.emit()

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.
        print("trigger signal received")

def main(argv):
    app = DestinyManager(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlEngine(app)
    component = QtQml.QQmlComponent(engine)
    component.loadUrl(QtCore.QUrl("exit.qml"))
    topLevel = component.create()
    if topLevel is not None:
        topLevel.show()
    else:
        for err in component.errors():
            print(err.toString())
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QObject,main(sys.argv)
```

Exit.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {

    Button {
    id: btn_Exit
    text: "Exit"

    onClicked: Qt.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as links - put the relevant parts in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question to include the code. If you try it, python might give some spacing errors, but the code does run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors in the python script, but ignoring those, the code can be made to work like this:

```
    def main(argv):
        app = DestinyManager(sys.argv)
        engine = QtQml.QQmlEngine(app)
        engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
        ...
```

Which is to say, you simply need to connect the qml `quit` signal to an appropriate slot in your python script.